# For which verb is を marking the object

Tags: grammar, translation, particle-を, adverbs, ellipsis

> 「にわかに目をキラキラさせ始めた友蔵**を**前に、さすがのおかあさんも、ズバリ、
>   そんな物は必要ないとは言いにくいらしく珍しく口ごもった。」

I'm struggling to parse this sentence. In particular I don't understand which verb the を in bold is marking the object of.

We have:
にわかに目をキラキラさせ始めた友蔵
"Tomozou whose eyes suddenly began to sparkle" is the object.

前に "in front of Tomozou..."

さすがのおかあさんも...珍しく口ごもった "Even mother (as she is) unusually, hesitated to say..."

Now I get confused. There is no と to mark what it is that she hesitated to say. Instead we have an adverbial phrase, which I think is:

物は必要ないとは言いにくいらしく "seemingly difficult to say that such a thing is unnecessary"

On second thoughts, perhaps this is the linking form 言いにくいらしく**て** rather than adverbial.

So I get something like:

> Even for (someone like) mother it seemed to be difficult to say in front of Tomozou that such a thing was unnecessary and, unusually, she hesitated to say it.

That seems to make sense but I still can't figure out the function of the を in bold. I fear I've messed something up here.

Please help me to parse this sentence correctly and understand the を in bold.

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18847/5010 http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/16288/5010 http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/20854/5010

Comment: @naruto That link certainly solved my main problem. In the second part of my question could you please confirm that I am correct in thinking that 言いにくいらしく is the written/formal form of 言いにくいらしくて rather than adverbially modifying 口ごもった?

Comment: Thinking about it again, I'm now favouring the adverbial option. I'm in a mess.

Comment: I think it's 言いにくいらしくて, which does not modify 口ごもった adverbially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

友蔵を前に is a shorthand for 友蔵を前にして

Xを前にする means "with X in front of [the subject]"