# Using 聴く instead of 聞く to mean "ask"?

Tags: word-choice, kanji, newspaper-grammar

I am reading this [article on NHK](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20210107/k10012800851000.html), but I am having a hard time understanding the title...

> 緊急事態宣言出すのを前に諮問委員会始まる 専門家に意見聴く

for the first part `緊急事態宣言出すのを前に諮問委員会始まる`

I am having a hard time parsing this. I understand:

> 緊急事態宣言出す - releasing the declaration of the state of emergency

> 諮問委員会始まる - Advisory committee begins

What is throwing me off is the **前に** after the **のを**...

if it was:

> 緊急事態宣言出すのを諮問委員会始まる - The advisory committee will begin the releasing of the declaration of the state of emergency.

or

> 緊急事態宣言出す前に諮問委員会始まる - The advisory committee will begin before  releasing of the declaration of the state of emergency.

**So what I think it means is this?! is it correct?**

> 緊急事態宣言出すのを前に諮問委員会始まる - The advisory committee will begin the releasing of the declaration of the state of emergency before. (before what??)

Now for the second part

> 専門家に意見聴く - Asking the opinion of a specialist.

**Why are they using 聴く and not 聞く or 訊く?**

if it was

> 専門家の意見（を）聴く - Hearing the opinion of a specialist.

I would be fine with it....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The particles を, が are omitted. The sentences are using "headline grammar". See:

- [what is the name of the abbreviated writing style used in newspapers?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14512/9831)

> 緊急事態宣言出すのを前に諮問委員会始まる 専門家に意見聴く

to rewrite it in normal grammar:

> 緊急事態宣言**を**出すのを前に諮問委員会**が**始まった。専門家に意見**を**聴いた。

literally:

"Prior to releasing the declaration of the state of emergency, the advisory committee began. (They) heard opinions from experts."

In 「～のを前に」, the の is a nominalizer. For 「Noun+を前に」"before/prior to~", see:

- [How does one analyze "N + を前に + V", where N is not an object of V](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18847/9831)

聴く looks more like "hear (someone's opinion)" or "listen (to someone's opinion)" (≂「耳を傾ける」) than 聞く which can be "ask (opinions from...)" (≂「(意見を)求める」). eg 公**聴**会

> 専門家の意見（を）聴く - Hearing the opinion of a specialist.

I agree that strictly grammatically, 「専門家**の/から**意見を**聴く**」 or 「専門家**に**意見を**聞く**」 would look more correct than 「専門家**に**意見を**聴く**」.

Comment: So basically, I should think of 「名詞＋を前に」as different way of expressing 「名詞 ＋ の前に」with a bit of a different nuance, right?

Am I correct to understand that 「誰々に意見を聴く」means "Listen TO someone's opinion" and 「誰々の意見を聴く」means "Hear someone's opinion"?

Comment: Yes, 名詞＋を前に has a different nuance from simple 名詞＋の前に. I don't think you'd commonly use/see 誰だれに意見を聴く. 誰だれの意見を聴く would mean "hear/listen to someone's opinion". だれだれにいけんをきく would normally be interpreted as 誰だれに意見を聞く/訊く, "ask someone for opinion".

Comment: oh my bad, I only used 「誰々」in the same way Japanese people use 「何々」when giving example sentences. I thought it worked the same way. But thank you for the explanation!